# set timeout to when a variable is fully initialized in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a rough code that logs an integer from a local variable but I had to set a timeout for the program to log the variable because without a timeout the log runs before the variable is initialized my question is is there a way to set the timeout until once the variable is initialized because a set time like 3000 is in definitive the amount of run time might change. Thanks in advance.

```js
var randomInt;

function testFun() {
    randomInt = 10;
}

setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Number is " + randomInt) }, 3000);

testFun()
```

Comment: What about promises?

Comment: Why not place it after calling testFun?

Comment: yes, that would work but I'm just wondering if there is a way to specifically set the timeout to once the variable is initialized. @WaisKamal

Comment: You could use setInterval instead and check if variable is defined. BUT, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the actual use case that you would need this?